# How do I install themes and icon packs in elementary OS 5.1?

Tags: release-hera, themes

I am totally new to elementary OS and I want to install new themes and icon packs. Please help me out by providing me with step by step guide on how to install themes and icon packs in elementary OS 5.1.
Thanks in advance ️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change theme, icons and fonts in elementary OS you need a third party app called elementary tweaks. Open the terminal and copy/paste these commands;

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

You can now find elementary tweaks in System Settings.

[image]

To get more themes to use in elementary OS you need to do following that will make two folders in your home directory. One for your themes and one for your icons:

```
cd
mkdir -p .themes
mkdir -p .icons
```

The two folders are hidden, so you need to right click in your file-browser and select **Show Hidden Files**.

Next thing is to head over to www.gnome-look.org and download a theme and some icons. The icons section is [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/132/order/latest/) and the theme section is [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/135/order/latest/). Unpack the icons to the .icons folder and unpack the theme to the .themes.

When it’s done go to System Settings and click Tweak.

Enjoy ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much ️

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark the question solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Storm Elemntary-tweaks did not work for me but [Pantheon](https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks) did.

Comment: `pantheon-tweaks` is for elementary OS 6 when the question is for elementary OS 5.1.

Comment: @jwillikers_1 I have elementary OS 5.1 as well but Pantheon just worked for me.